# Cómo crear URLs con parámetros | No llega el valor del parámetro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Al crear url con parámetros para utilizar posteriormente ese parámetro en controlador para hacer una consulta, no llega el parámetro al controlador. 404 NOT FOUND. ¿Qué sucede? En pregunta controller tengo un dd($categoria) para ver el valor que llega (animales, casa o viajes, depende cual se haga clic), pero no llega nada.

```
<a href="{{url('/preguntas',['categoria'=>'animales'])}}">Animales</a>
<a href="{{url('/preguntas',['categoria'=>'casa'])}}">Casa</a>
<a href="{{url('/preguntas',['categoria'=>'viajes'])}}">Viajes</a>
```

web.php tengo:

```
Route::any('/preguntas/{categoria}','PreguntaController@show');
```

Y en el controlador PreguntaController:

```
 public function show($categoria)
        {
            dd($categoria);
        }
```

Comment: porque utilizar `any` para definir tu ruta??, porque no simplemente utilizas `get`?, que mas hara tu ruta?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que no tengas la ruta definida dentro de un grupo, middleware, etc., primero comprobar que las rutas están bien "montadas" en la vista, entonces en routes:

```
Route::any('/preguntas/{categoria}', function($categoria) {
    dd('categoria -> ' . $categoria);
}); // 'PreguntaController@show');
```

La categoría se imprime, ahora pasamos a comprobar porque no llega al controlador. En routes, volvemos a poner la ruta como estaba:

```
Route::any('/preguntas/{categoria}','PreguntaController@show');
```

Y esto debe de funcionar, si como te he dicho, a la ruta no se le aplica ningún "filtro" dentro de routes, y si el controlador no está en un namespace diferente de `App\Http\Controllers`.

#### En resumen...

Debes comprobar, primero donde está definida la ruta y que la imprimes correctamente en la vista. Estará en el fichero de rutas, fuera de grupos middleware, donde se aplica un prefijo, etc, de otro modo las rutas no estarían bien en la vista y lo que hice no habría funcionado. Entonces la url en el enlace de la página sería algo como:

```
http://laravel.test/preguntas/animales
```

Finalmente, comprobar que el parámetro llega al controlador, nada que apuntar con respecto al método que pusiste. Solo comprobar que el nombre del controlador y su namespace sean correctos.

Comment: En el primer caso funciona perfecto. Muestra el dd('categoria -> ' . $categoria) perfectamente. En la segunda comprobación, devuelve un 404 NOT FOUND. ¿Qué puede suceder?

Comment: @anderson si los namespaces son correctos y la ruta existe, ejecuta el comando `composer autoload` por si el controlador no está registrado.

Answer (score 0):

En primera no veo la razon por el cual utilizas `any` para tu ruta, en lo personal creo que seria mejor solo un `get`:

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{categoria}','PreguntaController@show');
```

ademas es recomendable siempre ponerle un `name` a tu ruta para posterior poder utilizar el helper `route`  en cambio de `url`, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{categoria}','PreguntaController@show')->name('preguntas.categoria');
```

y tus etiquetas `a` quedarian de la siguiente forma::

```
<a href="{{route('preguntas.categoria',['animales'])}}">Animales</a>
<a href="{{route('preguntas.categoria',['casa'])}}">Casa</a>
<a href="{{route('preguntas.categoria',['viajes'])}}">Viajes</a>
```

En caso de no querer colocar el `name` a tus rutas es mas sencillo

```
<a href="{{url('/preguntas/animales')}}">Animales</a>
<a href="{{url('/preguntas/casa')}}">Casa</a>
<a href="{{url('/preguntas/viajes')}}">Viajes</a>
```